# Assumption of Poisson regression with robust standard errors

Tags: logistic, poisson-distribution, poisson-regression, epidemiology, relative-risk

I am applying a Poisson regression with robust standard errors to model a binary response variables. I was wondering what are the assumptions underlying this type of regression?

I understand that the response values have to be independent, and the conditional distribution of the response need not be Poisson (of course, since we are dealing with binary data). Nevertheless, the link function has to be a log function; how does this assumption work for binary response, and how would it be assessed?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please explain what a "Poisson regression with robust standard errors" refers to? How is it a Poisson regression if you have a binary response?

Comment: @frank Poisson regression is a generalized linear model usually used for count outcomes. Robust standard errors are a specific method of computing the standard errors that are robust to violations of distributional assumptions. Poisson regression is potentially valid here because the outcome is a non-negative integer. It is not uncommon to use Poisson regression for modeling binary data.

Comment: [Chen et al. (2018)](https://doi.org/10.1186/s12874-018-0519-5) might be a useful resource.